# Is there a better way of keeping track of the list index whilst iterating through a list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, indexing, iteration

Currently the method uses a `for()` loop and a `foreach()` loop to iterate through each array element in the list to compare a value inside the array elements. I require the for loop to record the current index value of the list if the criteria is met so that I know where to rebuild the list afterwards.

```
// update high score list
public void updateScores()
{
    // if the list of scores isnt empty compare score
    if (list.Count() != 0)
    {
        // loop through each array in the list
        for (int i = 0; i <= list.Count(); i++)
        {
            // look into each linedata array in the list
            foreach (string[] ld in list)
            {
                // only look at scores that are the same difficulty
                if (lineData[1] == difficulty)
                {
                    // if score is greater than this score in list
                    if (score > Convert.ToInt32(lineData[0]))
                    {
                        // record which index the score was higher than
                        scoreIndex = i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // if the score is higher than one of the saved highscores remove all lower score down one index
        for (int i = list.Count() - 1; i > scoreIndex; i--)
        {
            // continue
        }
    }
}
```

This is how the list is built:

```
// load highscores
public bool LoadScores()
{
    // attempt to load the highscore list
    if (File.Exists("highScores"))
    {
        // loop through each line in the file
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // seperate the score from the difficulty
            lineData = line.Split(',');

            // add each line to the list
            list.Add(lineData);
        }
        return true;
    }
    else{return false;}
}
```

highscores text file:

```
1231,1
1231232,2
4664,2
252,1
475532,1
```

Question: Is there a better way of keeping track of the list index whilst iterating through a list.

Edit: Basically I am comparing a players score with a list of highscores. If the score is high enough lower scores will be moved down to allow the new score into the list

Comment: I'm sure your query can be more succinct with Linq, but it's hard to tel from the code you've posted.  Can you describe what your intended _results_ are?

Comment: I have updated my question. Basically I am comparing a players score with a list of highscores. If the score is high enough lower scores will be moved down to allow the new score into the list.

Comment: The comments for this code don't match what the code is actually doing, but based on your comment to the question, what you really want is a linq query to do a union(both lists) + sort + select (limit to number of high scores) to create a new high scores list.

Comment: I have updated the comments sorry about that.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Could you give me an example of what you suggested?

Comment: The question assumes you want to keep track of a list index. An easier way of doing this won't require keeping track of list indexes.

Comment: @crm Take a step back. It seems the problem can be expressed in simpler terms. I would expect high-scores to be ordered. So long as you only save the highest 10 it would be efficient enough and more readable to simply append all scores to the list `list.Add(potentialNewHighScore)`, then sort the list by score descending and take 10? `list = list.OrderByDescending(s => s.Score).Take(10).ToList()`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Thanks for the suggestion, going to try it. I wasn't aware I could order a list the way you suggested, thanks.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Am I correct in assuming that it is grabbing the index `Score` and applying it the variables `s`? How do I name my indexes likes this or can I identify an index using its number? Currently I want to order by the 1st indexed element which is the scores.

Comment: @crm Sorry, my example was just generic code. `s` is just the lambda expression's parameter alias for each item being iterated. It didn't directly correlate to the code you gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Preamble :)

Have you ever tried to execute your code? :)

1. You have a bug: outer loop will run out of list bounds.
2. Checking for list size before iterating through it is usually unnecessary.
3. I don't see any code to sort list before executing updateScores. Your code will provide unexpected results on unsorted lists.
4. You are using strings now. Sorting array of strings is definitely not what you want. Consider using structs with integers for high scores values.

## Answering your question

1. You can just start inner loop from outer loop and use break statement. See example:

   ```
   public void updateScores()
   {
       // loop through each array in the list
       for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
       {
           string[] lineData = list[i];
           if (lineData[1] == difficulty)
           {
               if (score > Convert.ToInt32(lineData[0]))
               {
                   // if the score is higher than one of the saved highscores remove all lower score down one index
                   for (int j = list.Count() - 1; j > scoreIndex; j--)
                   {
                       // continue
                   }
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Negating conditions can simplify the code:

   ```
   public void updateScores()
   {
       // loop through each array in the list
       for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
       {
           string[] lineData = list[i];
           if (lineData[1] != difficulty)
               continue;
           if (score <= Convert.ToInt32(lineData[0]))
               continue;
           // if the score is higher than one of the saved highscores remove all lower score down one index
           for (int j = list.Count() - 1; j > scoreIndex; j--)
           {
               // continue
           }
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 6):

First of all, Sergey is correct; this code is a mass of bugs and bad practices. Two that Sergey did not mention are:

- The standard in C# is to `PascalCase` your method names, not `camelCase` them.
- Don't call the extension method `Count()` on an `IList`. Use the `Count` property.

I would recommend that you get in the habit of writing smaller methods that call each other, and then carefully test each one.

As some commenters noted, you can solve this problem more easily by maintaining a sorted list, taking the union of the old list and the new item, sorting that sequence, truncating it to include only the top n, turning that back into a list, and you're done.

None of that answers your question, which was

> Is there a better way of keeping track of the list index whilst iterating through a list?

I submit to you that this is not quite the right question to ask. A better question is:

> How can I determine the index of the first item in a list which matches a given condition?

Make an extension method in a static class:

```
    public static int? FirstIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate) 
    {
      if (items == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
      if (predicate == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");
      int index = 0;
      foreach (var item in items) 
      {
        if (predicate(item))
          return index;
        index += 1;
      }
      return null;
    }
```

This extension method takes a sequence and a predicate and returns the index of the first item that matches the predicate, or null if no item matches the predicate. Note that this works on any sequence, not just an `IList` -- the `[]` indexer and `Count` property are not used.

Comment: Thanks, you raised a number of points that I wasn't aware of before.